# Cant send email using PHP - get email sent messeage but no email is sent actually

Tags: php, html, forms, smtp

I tried to send mail using the SMTP server and I did all configurations. I got the message that say email sent thank you. But when I go to my email account there is no mail. Also, since I am trying to send an email from my mail address to another address, I got mail that says someone tries to login your account. What I understand here is that the code is able to login to my account but can't sent the mail. What is the problem might be here?

Here what I did in sendmail.ini file:

**

- smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
- smtp_port=465
- smtp_ssl=ssl
- default_domain=localhost
- error_logfile=error.log
- debug_logfile=debug.log
- auth_username=[mygmailadress]@gmail.com
- auth_password=[mypassword]
- pop3_server=
- pop3_username=
- pop3_password=
- force_sender=
- force_recipient=
- hostname=localhost

**

here is my code:

```
  <?php 
   ini_set("SMTP","ssl://smtp.gmail.com");
   ini_set("smtp_port","465");
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$to = "mygmailadres@gmail.com"; // this is my Email address 
$from = $_POST['email']; // this is the user's Email address
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$subject = "Form submission";
$subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
$message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
$message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

$headers = "From:" . $from;
$headers2 = "From:" . $to;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";

   }
 ?>

 <!DOCTYPE html><head><title>Form submission</title></head><body>


<form action="" method="post">
 First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name"><br>
 Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
 Message:<br><textarea rows="5" name="message" cols="30"></textarea><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
 </form></body>
</html>
```

Comment: A common problem is that the e-mail turns up in the SPAM folder, have you checked that?

Comment: Yes I checked but still, there is no mail

Comment: @Yasemin have you enabled IMAP access in your gmail? [link](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en)

Comment: I would use PHPMailler https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer much easier.

Comment: Yes I enabled IMAP access @Karthick.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of settings needs to be done in GMAIL in order to make it work. Please check below points.

1. Please ensure that 2-steps-verification is disabled in GMail if you are using GMail’s SMTP server to send email (sending email using GMail), otherwise you might get “Email sent” message but the email won’t get sent actually.
2. Enable IMAP access which is already done in your account.
3. You might need to allow less secure apps to access your account in GMAIL. Follow the [link](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?p=BadCredentials&visit_id=637235815198793667-2348200700&rd=2#cantsignin) & direct link for [secure apps](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)

It worked for me when I tried all above steps. If none of them works, then you need to check error log file to identify the exact cause why it stops sending email.

Comment: I did all steps that you mentioned. still, it is not working

Comment: @Yasemin Check your error.log file and it may have more information about the issue. I'm able to send email using GMAIL SMTP after setting up with instruction I mentioned above.